# Keras ImageDataGenerator for segmentation with images and masks in separate directories

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, image-segmentation

I am trying to build a semantic segmentation model using `tensorflow.keras`. The dataset that I am using has the images and masks stored in separate directories and each filename has is an id for mapping an image file with its respective mask.

Following is the structure of my dataset directory:

```
new
   - rendered_imges
      - render
         - image_1.tif
         - image_2.tif
         - image_3.tif
   - ground_truths
      - masks
         - mask_1.tif
         - mask_2.tif
         - mask_3.tif
```

In the above directory structure, `image_{i}.tif` corresponds to `mask_{i}.tif`.

I tried writing an `ImageDataGenerator` for augmenting both the images and their respective masks in exactly the same way. My approach was the following:

```
SEED = 100

image_data_generator = ImageDataGenerator(
    width_shift_range = 0.1,
    height_shift_range = 0.1,
    rotation_range = 10,
    zoom_range = 0.1
).flow_from_directory('./new/rendered_images', batch_size = 16, target_size = (150, 150), seed = SEED)

mask_data_generator = ImageDataGenerator(
    width_shift_range = 0.1,
    height_shift_range = 0.1,
    rotation_range = 10,
    zoom_range = 0.1
).flow_from_directory('./new/ground_truths', batch_size = 16, target_size = (150, 150), seed = SEED)
```

With the above approach although I am getting the same augmentations applied to both image and mask, the images are not getting paired with their respective masks according to their filenames. It would be great if someone can suggest a way to do this properly using Keras or Tensorflow.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You will need to make a new function that will generate both the training image and corresponding mask that you will use to feed into the `fit_generator` method.  Specifically, the way `fit_generator` works is that yields a sequence of tuples such that the first element of the tuple is the image and the second element of the tuple is the expected output.  By simply using the data generator on its own, the sub-directories will implicitly encode the expected label of the image.  This is of course no longer the case when you're trying to do semantic segmentation.

Therefore, create a new function that will output a collection of tuples that give you the image **and** the mask.  In summary, you will simply take the two `ImageDataGenerators` that you created, `zip` them together, then have a loop that will yield each batch of training images and expected output labels.

One final thing I need to mention is that the **filenames for both directories need to match** if you want to successfully pair the image and corresponding mask.  For example, if you have a training image called `1.tif` in your `rendered_imges/render` subdirectory, you will need to name your corresponding mask the same way in `ground_truths/mask`.  The reason is that even though you match the seeds, it will randomly choose the filenames before loading the images in memory, so to make sure that the same order of selection is maintained among the training images and corresponding masks, their filenames also need to match.  Make sure you do that before we proceed here.

Therefore, do something like this:

```
def my_image_mask_generator(image_data_generator, mask_data_generator):
    train_generator = zip(image_data_generator, mask_data_generator)
    for (img, mask) in train_generator:
        yield (img, mask)
```

Next, create your data generators as you did normally:

```
SEED = 100

image_data_generator = ImageDataGenerator(
    width_shift_range = 0.1,
    height_shift_range = 0.1,
    rotation_range = 10,
    zoom_range = 0.1
).flow_from_directory('./new/rendered_images', batch_size = 16, target_size = (150, 150), seed = SEED)

mask_data_generator = ImageDataGenerator(
    width_shift_range = 0.1,
    height_shift_range = 0.1,
    rotation_range = 10,
    zoom_range = 0.1
).flow_from_directory('./new/ground_truths', batch_size = 16, target_size = (150, 150), seed = SEED)
```

Finally, call the `fit_generator` method on your model.  Assuming you've already constructed the model correctly:

```
from keras.optimizers import Adam
# Your other related imports here...

# Create custom generator for training images and masks
my_generator = my_image_mask_generator(image_data_generator, mask_data_generator)

model = ... # Define your model here
# Compile your model here
model.compile(optimizer = Adam(lr = 1e-4), loss = 'binary_crossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy'])

# Train your model here
model.fit_generator(my_generator,...)
```

Take note that given your directory structure, it looks like you are performing a binary segmentation per image, so that's why I chose binary cross-entropy as the loss function.

Comment: How could you load and augment images when pixels are already present in the Dataframe like in [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59596784/custom-imagedatagenerator-for-half-a-million-images-where-labels-and-pixels-ar)? Could you please answer it there?

Comment: @rayryeng how the validation will work here?

Comment: @MSI it would be using exactly the same mechanism. You'd create the two generators for the image and mask, and the final validation generator exactly the same way. In the `fit_generator` method, there should be an additional input variable you supply named `validation_data` that takes in the validation generator.

Comment: But I have a single directory. Structure ( dataset -> Images/* , Mask/*). Normally we do split in 'datagen' then use 'flow_from_directory' to get 'train' & 'validation' aug sets. I am confused about this part as my dataset doesn't have a separate train & validation part.

Comment: @MSI In the `ImageDataGenerator` call, you can specify `validation_split` which will set aside a fraction of the data for validation. You must make sure the masks and images are named the same way in both directories.

Comment: @rayryeng can you check this? [codeshareio-mycode](https://codeshare.io/xvemEN) , here I am facing an error of unexpected keyword argument 'subset' !

Comment: @MSI The `subset` keyword belongs in the `flow_from_directory` call, not the `ImageDataGenerator` call.

Comment: @rayryeng Thanks! it worked! But here my model input layer->[(None, 256, 256, 3) & the
output->(None, 256, 256, 1)] when using "model.fit_generator(my_generator, steps_per_epoch=2000,epochs=50)" is having an error like -> [ Layer model_1 expects 1 input(s), but it received 2 input tensors ]

 //   I used ---- > my_generator= zip(image_data_generator_training, mask_data_generator_training)

Comment: @MSI Try looking at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58050113/imagedatagenerator-for-semantic-segmentation